# Regex to replace %variables%

Tags: python, regex

I've been yanking clumps of hair out for 30 minutes doing this one...

I have a dictionary, like so:

```
{'search': 'replace',
 'foo':    'bar'}
```

And a string like this:

```
Foo bar %foo% % search %.
```

I'd like to replace each variable with it's equivalent text from the dictionary:

```
Foo bar bar replace.
```

My current regex fails, so here it is (`key` and `value` are from `dictionary.items()`):

```
 re.sub(r'%\d+' + key + '[^%]\d+%', value, text)
```

Any help would be appreciated, as this regex stuff is driving me nuts...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're flexible with your syntax in your string, Python has a built in mechanism for that:

```
>>> print 'Hello, %(your_name)s, my name is %(my_name)s' % {'your_name': 'Blender', 'my_name': 'Ken'}
Hello, Blender, my name is Ken
```

Alternatively, if you want that syntax, I'd avoid regular expressions and just do this:

```
>>> vars = {'search': 'replace',
...  'foo':    'bar'}
>>> mystring = "Foo bar %foo% % search %."
>>> for k, v in vars.items():
...     mystring = mystring.replace('%%%s%%' % k, v)
... 
>>> print mystring
Foo bar bar % search %.
```

Comment: I didn't know that the `%d` thing could take variable names. Thanks. I can do a blind search-and-replace, but I'd also like to account for whitespace (which is why I tried the regex). I'll keep fiddling with it...

Comment: On second thought, the `%` will be troublesome. I think I'll go with the parentheses too, as it's much easier to implement and works well. Any way I can omit the `d` at the end? I'm using this for a template engine, so the simpler the syntax the better.

Comment: Your alternative doesn't work to well. It can do undesired double-interpolation. e.g. `{ 'foo': '%bar%', 'bar': 'baz' }`. @murgatroid99's solution isn't affected by this problem.

Comment: I ended up using `%(this)%` syntax, as the percentage signs would be quite hard to deal with and escape when writing. Search and replace > regex.

Answer (score 4):

If you want it in one statement, you could do the following (assuming s is the string and d is the dictionary):

```
re.sub(r"[%]\s*[^%]+\s*[%]",lambda k:d.get(k[1,-1].strip(),k),s)
```

This uses a function in the replacement part to get each value from the dictionary, and ignores if it is not in the dictionary.

**Edit:** fixed bug with unwanted whitespace appearing in lookup key

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't the following regex just work?

```
re.sub(r'%\s?' + key + '\s?%', value, text)
```

The only thing that's a bit special are the optional spaces; they can be matched with `\s?`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the replacement function support of `re.sub`:

```
def replace(s, kw, pattern=re.compile(r'%\s*(\w+)\s*%')):
    """
    Replace delimited keys in a string with values from kw.

    Any pattern may be used, as long as the first group defines the lookup key.
    """
    lookup = lambda match: kw.get(match.group(1), match.group())
    return pattern.sub(lookup, s)

>>> replace('Foo bar %foo% % search %.', {'search': 'replace', 'foo': 'bar'})
'Foo bar bar replace.'
```

You can change the `lookup` function to customize how lookup errors are treated, and so on.