# Python regex, pulling patterns out of a match and using them as input back into the match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have searched for an answer.  I am sure they are out there, but there are way too many false hits.

This is my script (my attempt fails):

```
#!/bin/env python

import re

usage="""
    My favorite restaurant is <<<res>>>
    My favorite person is <<<per>>>
"""

res="pizza hut"
per="my sister"

def main():
    value = re.sub(r'<<<(\w+)>>>', globals()[r'\1'], usage)
    print 'value=%s.' % (value)

if ( __name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

What I am trying to output is:

```
value=
    My favorite restaurant is pizza hut
    My favorite person is my sister
.
```

The closest [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206804/regex-to-replace-variables) that I have seen, involves maintaining a separate list.  I do not want to have to maintain a separate list.

Comment: Why are you using `globals()` here? There is no global name `\1` in your code (nor could there be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dangerous way using `eval`:

```
def repl(match):
    return eval(match.group(0)[3:-3])

print re.sub(r'<<<\w+>>>', repl, usage)
```

Output:

```
My favorite restaurant is pizza hut
My favorite person is my sister
```

Comment: Wait, out of all the answers you choose the one with `eval()`?

Comment: `The closest answer that I have seen, involves maintaining a separate list. I do not want to have to maintain a separate list.` I gave the solution without using a separate list or dict.

Comment: Yes this is the closest to what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function as the replacement in `re.sub()`.  The function will receive the [match object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) as the only argument and should return a string.  The best way to do this is to create a dictionary with your replacements:

```
import re

usage="""
    My favorite restaurant is <<<res>>>
    My favorite person is <<<per>>>
"""

rep = {"res": "pizza hut",
       "per": "my sister"}

print re.sub(r'<<<(\w+)>>>', lambda m: rep.get(m.group(1), ""), usage)
```

You could use this exact same method with `globals()`, but using `globals()` in this way is generally discouraged when a dictionary offers the same behavior in a safer way.

Comment: ahhh you beat me :P by alot ... how did I not see this (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried it and it worked, so I gave you an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

Use a `dict` instead of using variables, and change `<<<res>>>` to `{res}` using regex so that you can use string formatting on it:

```
>>> import re
>>> usage="""                                   
    My favorite restaurant is <<<res>>>
    My favorite person is <<<per>>>
"""
>>> my_dict = {'res':'pizza hut', 'per':'my sister'}
>>> print re.sub(r'<<<(\w+)>>>', r'{\1}', usage).format(**my_dict)

    My favorite restaurant is pizza hut
    My favorite person is my sister
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you free to modify the formatting? Python already supports this by doing:

```
usage = """
    My favorite restaurant is {res}
    My favorite person is {per}
"""
res = "pizza hut"
per = "my sister"

print usage.format(**globals())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried it and it worked, so I gave you an upvote!

Comment: I do not know that my final usage string might need to have a "{some stuff}" pattern in it that is not a intended for replacement.  Because of this I might have to change the replacement pattern to insure all are intended to be replaced by variable values.  I want to be able to change this (i.e. to `__VAR(???)__`, instead of `<<<???>>>`).